# How to identify an event and pass it as a parameter to the callback function in JS?

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback

I made several tests and searched online but couldn't find a solution to this.

I have the following code below which spawns 4 timeout events.

```
for (let w=1; w<=4; w++) {
    var eventname = "event"+w;
    this[eventname] = setTimeout(DoStuff(this), 1000);
}

function DoStuff (myref) {
    console.log(myref)
}
```

I need a way of pass to the callback function a reference of whose of the 4 events is invoking it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third and all subsequent parameters in the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function can be used to pass parameters with.

So in your case, pass the `eventname` reference to `setTimeout` after the `delay` argument, and only reference the `DoStuff` function without calling it.

```
for (let w=1; w<=4; w++) {
  var eventname = "event"+w;
  this[eventname] = setTimeout(DoStuff, 1000, eventname);
}
```

Comment: Cool! And thanks for this! Just a side note- the correct in this case would be setTimeout (DoStuff, 1000, eventname) though. Passing *this* as parameter it will return the window instead. :-)